# PrimeNg dropdowns not updating other dropdowns when sharing same formControl

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I'm trying to use multiple primeng dropdowns with reactive forms, these dropdowns share the same formControl instance, but for some reason when changing the value of one dropdown it doesn't change the visible value of the other ones.

Here is my code for the view:

```
<form [formGroup]="mainGroup">
First Select:<br/>
<p-dropdown
  [options]="options"
  formControlName="main">
</p-dropdown>
<br/>
<br/>
Second Select:<br/>
<p-dropdown
  [options]="options"
  formControlName="main">
</p-dropdown>
</form>
<br/>
<b>Actual value:</b> {{mainGroup.value.main}}
```

The component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  fb: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder

  mainGroup = this.fb.group({
    'main': []
  })

  options = [
    {label: 'First', value: 'First'},
    {label: 'Second', value: 'Second'},
    {label: 'Third', value: 'Third'}
  ]
}
```

And a working sample on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug)

Is there a work around or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually set the values, it will not update directly, if you want to update directly on change, you have to use [(ngModel)].

There is a bug around it. [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10036)

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-b14qyp)

Put this in constructor

```
constructor(){
    this.mainGroup.get('main').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.mainGroup.get('main').setValue(value, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false, 
      emitModelToViewChange: true });
    }, error => {}, () => { });
}
```